# how to use hyperlink in wpf to get a file in network drive?

Tags: wpf, hyperlink

I have a web application...where I can get an excel file from network drive...using

..So I am not using any impersonation.

Do we have something similar to that in WPF ?

**EDIT**:
I want to open excel file in network location...when user click a link or button. Also, i dont want to use any impersonation...as we dont have to impersonate in case of a-href.

Comment: you want to access for excel file using a hyperlink button in WPF?

Comment: I want to open excel file in network location...when user click a link or button. Also, i dont want to use any impersonation...as we dont have to impersonate in case of a-href.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="file:///networkShare/file">
    Excel File
</Hyperlink>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include the `Hyperlink` inside a `TextBlock` and use a `ValueConverter` to Reference To the network Value.

inside: View.xaml

```
            <TextBlock x:Name="FileNamePresenter" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding FileName}" Margin="0,0,0.001,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" Width="Auto" Grid.Column="1" >
            <Hyperlink x:Name="FileLink" NavigateUri="{Binding FileName,  ConverterParameter=FileName, Converter={StaticResource FileConverter}}"/>
            </TextBlock>
```

valueConverter

```
namespace some.Helpers
{
    public  class JobFileConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string FileLocationPath = "";
            try
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    FileLocationPath= string.Format(@"file://SomesServer/f$/SomeFile/{0}.pdf",value);


                }

            }
            catch { }
            return FileLocationPath;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

and lastly inside App.xaml ( or resource dictionary)  the glue as it were...

```
<Application x:Class="some.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:some.ViewModel"
             xmlns:helper="clr-namespace:some.Helpers"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             StartupUri="JobList.xaml"
             mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="someApp.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!--Global View Model Locator-->
            <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"
                d:IsDataSource="True" />
            <helper:JobStatusImageConverter  x:Key="JobStatusConverter"/>
            <helper:JobBindingImageConverter x:Key="JobBindingConverter"/>
            <helper:JobFileConverter x:Key="FileConverter"/>
            <Style x:Key="HeadingStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
                <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="None"/>
                <Setter Property="Effect">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DropShadowEffect Color="#FFA52323" Direction="339" ShadowDepth="0"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this solution: [How to make a simple hyperlink in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531621/how-to-make-a-simple-hyperlink-in-xaml)
to make a button look like a hyperlink. (Hyperlinks don't work everywhere.)
When clicking the button, do something like this:

```
Process explorer = new Process();  
explorer.StartInfo.FileName="explorer.exe";  
explorer.StartInfo.Arguments = "/n, /e, /select," + path;  
explorer.Start();
```