# WPF- Cut-off issue in WrapPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

when i use  more than one controls inside the **wrap Panel** if any control contains lengthy text (more than the window size) cut-off is happening. (See the image)

[image: cutoff happens for lengthy text block]

I have two textblocks and one button control.

```
  <Grid>
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Very long Text Message contains long text for testing " FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
            <Button Content="sample Text"></Button>
            <TextBlock Text="sample Text  textblock"></TextBlock>

        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
```

the cut-off happens for first text block. i want wrap to next line if the text contains more characters.

help me to solve the issue. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to make a single paragraph that wraps? If so, then `WrapPanel` isn't actually what you want.

`WrapPanel` takes UI elements (rectangular chunks of real estate) and lays them out left-to-right, top-to-bottom. You could enable wrapping in your first `TextBlock`, but then it'll take up a rectangle of screen space that's two lines high. Because the `TextBlock` fills that entire rectangle, the button will actually appear *under* it, rather than to the right of the bold words "for testing ".

If you want to make the whole thing flow like a paragraph, you don't want to use *UI* elements (which are always rectangular chunks); you want to use *text* elements (which flow in paragraphs).

The way to get text elements into your XAML is to wrap them in a `TextBlock`. Try this:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
        <Bold>
            <Run Text="Very long Text Message contains long text for testing " />
        </Bold>
        <Button Content="sample Text"></Button>
        sample Text  textblock
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Note that I wrapped the first chunk of text in a `<Run>` element -- otherwise the trailing space would be ignored (assumed to be whitespace in your XAML document). The second chunk of text didn't have leading or trailing spaces, so I just put it directly inline.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252560/87399) has a bit more about the difference between the "controls" and "text" sides of XAML.

Comment: cutoff is happening when button contains long text.

Comment: If you want everything to flow as a paragraph, you should really consider using a [`Hyperlink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a `Button`. Hyperlinks are text elements and will word-wrap like text; buttons (being UI elements, and therefore rectangular chunks of real estate) will not wrap as gracefully. If you really want a button, try changing `<Button>Text</Button>` to `<Button><TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">Text</TextBlock></Button>` and see if you like the results, but that'll be the best you can do with a `Button`.

Comment: thanks @joe. but the thing is i have to add hyperlink inside the **ItemsControl** . when i try to add it showing error like **A value of type 'Hyperlink' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection' **

Comment: `ItemsControl` is from the "UI elements" side of WPF, and expects to contain UI elements. `Hyperlink` is from the "text elements" side of WPF. To use text elements in an `ItemsControl`, you need to wrap them in a `TextBlock` (which is a UI element, but knows how to contain text elements -- it's an adapter between the UI-element and text-element halves of WPF). The link at the bottom of my answer has more detail.

Answer (score 4):

You need the attribute `TextWrapping="Wrap"` in  your textbox

```
<TextBlock 
   Text="Very long Text Message contains long text for testing " 
   FontWeight="Bold"   
   TextWrapping="Wrap">
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: cutoff is happening when button contains long text.