# how do i change the color for some part of the labels content

Tags: c#, wpf

are there a way to change a some part of the labels content in C#?

i know you can do that in the xaml but thats just for manualy typing in the text

i want

```
Resultatfor_nu_Copy.Content = oprofilbox.Text(green) + "/(yellow)" +  obredebox.Text(green) + "-(yellow)" + oFælgestr.Text(green);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create multiple [`Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run(v=vs.110).aspx) instances, each with its own color, and add them to a [`TextBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock(v=vs.110).aspx)'s [`Inlines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines(v=vs.110).aspx) collection.

```
var textBlock = new TextBlock();
textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run("Green") { Foreground = Brushes.Green });
textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run("Yellow") { Foreground = Brushes.Yellow });
myLabel.Content = textBlock;
```

(If you're curious about why the `TextBlock` needs to be there, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252560/87399) might interest you.)

Comment: nvm i figured out i had to do colorconverter for that and ty that was exactly what i have been looking for

Comment: To use custom colors, you'd have to create your own SolidColorBrush instance (instead of using one of the ready-made ones from the Brushes class).